# I m not able to open pdf which is in blog in web view, its open in default it is very slow in android application .I need to open pdf in google drive

Tags: android

Im creating a app that contain web view in that web view I'm loading a a blog that contain pdfs... im tring to open pdf in app its open in a default web view pdf viewer.. in similar application I found that there pdf are open in google drive... so I need to open a pdf in a google drive which is in web view with blog please can anyone help me...

im try to integrate a google drive api also but it didn't work for me.

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ClMate_cse_1_1_web);

    // Enable Javascript

    init();
    listener();
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://todaybtech.blogspot.com/p/i-year-ii-sem-cse-materials.html");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());




    mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);

        }

    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();


    }
```

I m trying to open a pdf which is in web view that loads a blog in that blog contain pdfs...its opening in a very slow default web view browser.i need to open in google drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the below code :

```
String pdf = "http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Comment: in my WebView has a blog it contain more pdfs and it will be uploaded in real time...so please help me